# How to you CASE for IF THEN issue?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to select rows that fall under these conditions

```
    IF kid=IND and kid=Family 
       then select Kid=IND 

    If kid only has Family 
       then select family. 

    if kid only has IND 
       then select IND.
```

How would I go about doing this using CASE?

ex.

```
kid_id   date       type

001      1/1/2013   IND
001      1/1/2013   Family
002      1/2/2013   Family
003      1/3/2013   IND
```

Results

```
001   1/1/2013   IND
002   1/2/2013   Family
003   1/3/2013   IND
```

Comment: For SQL questions it's often useful to include a short example of the relevant columns of the input table and a short example of the desired output.  That would help us give you a better answer.  Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16715247/edit) your question.

Comment: Ok sorry, new to this. But thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
case 
When (kid=ind and kid=family) Then ind
When kid=family then family
When kid=ind then ind
else
  null
end

From SomeTable
```

given kid, ind and family are columns in the table.

Do you mean something like this

```
select kid_id,date, 
case 
When (kid=ind and kid=family) Then 'Both'
When kid=family then family
When kid=ind then ind
else
  'None'
end as TypeGroup

From SomeTable
```

Comment: This is what I have sooo far but I can't get past the and       where type=case type when ('ind' and 'family') then 'ind' when 'family' then 'family' else 'ind' end

Comment: Far from clear what you want or mean. Added a bit more based on a total guess. Explain in english instead of using where case and if, as I believe we are suffering from a semantics failure.